# Infinite lazy list in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

Is it possible to **simply** check in Scala if an `LazyList` is infinite? Or maybe there is a data structure like `cats.data.NonEmptyLazyList` which could be used to represent an infinite lazy list?

Comment: e.g. to create an infinite `LazyList` we can use `LazyList.continually` method, which in a naive implementation may just store a flag `isInfinite`. I know that it's impossible to implement the `isInfinite` method on a lazy structure due to the halting problem, therefore i'm actually looking for an enriched data structure

Comment: `NonEmptyLazyList` could have one element and still be non-empty. If you want to have list that has to be infinite I would look at some recursive scheme like Nu combined with a tuple or Cofree on some lazy `F`.

Comment: Actually, you would need a fuzzy logic to enrich such a data structure: certainly finite OR certainly infinite OR maybe infinite. Imagine a sequence that is actually reading some hardware sensor, or network data stream, or something like that. It is well probable that one moment "end of data" will be signalled. But it is not or should not be predictable.

Answer (score 1):

`NonEmptyLazyList` could have one element and still be non-empty.

If you want to have a list that has to be infinite I would look at some recursive scheme like Nu combined with a tuple (`type Stream[A] = Nu[(A, *)]`) or `Cofree` of `Id` (`Cofree[Id, A]` - in Cats `tail` is lazy because of `Eval`). They have to be infinite *by design* as there is no way for you to terminate the stream of values.

There are some sources with examples referring to [Matryoshka](https://github.com/precog/matryoshka) (including mine) but nowadays [Droste](https://github.com/higherkindness/droste) seems more actively developed.

But if you are using some `LazyList`, `scala.collection.Stream`, `Iterator`, `Iterable` etc it is (in general case) impossible to verify if this collection will be infinite or not. Halting problem and stuff.